# Using CMD to output datetime as long

Tags: cmd, terminal

How do I run a CMD command and get the timestamp as a long. For example if the below code outputs the time as: `echo %time%`  >> `23:51:39.20`

Instead of hours:min:seconds.m_sec how can I display a long value ?

What I mean by long is that I want to display the time as `Unix epoch time`

Comment: What do you mean with "a long value"? Please give an example of the desired output.

Comment: I want a ` Unix epoch time`

Comment: Install [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and run `bash -c 'date "+%s" -d "%time:~,-3%"'`

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd` you can use the help of PowerShell:

```
powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"
```

or to get it into a variable:

```
echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
  powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"
  ') do set "epochtime=%%a"
echo %epochtime%
```